# How to apply default post filter with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to implement an engine of backtesting using elasticsearch. To be able to do that I would need to filter the hits by excluding the ones that are posterior to the testing date and I would like to do that by default because the algorithm (that I want to backtest) is not supposed to know about the backtesting.

In other words, is it possible to apply a default post filter to ElasticSearch queries?

For example, let's say that those documents are in ES:

```
{ name: 'Jean', weight: 70, date: 2012-01-01 }
{ name: 'Jules', weight: 70, date: 2010-01-01 }
{ name: 'David', weight: 80, date: 2010-01-01 }
```

I want to apply a default post filter to exclude documents posterior to 2011 in a way that if I do a query to get every persons with a weight of 70, the only result I have is Jules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [Filtered Aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered).  When you query through the alias, the filter is automatically applied to your query...which hides it from your application:

```
// Insert the data
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/people/data/" -d'
{ "name": "Jean", "weight" : 70, "date": "2012-01-01" }'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/people/ata" -d'
{ "name": "Jules", "weight" : 70, "date": "2010-01-01" }'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/people/data/" -d'
{ "name": "David", "weight" : 80, "date": "2010-01-01" }'

// Add a filtered alias
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_aliases" -d'
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "people",
                 "alias" : "filtered_people",
                 "filter" : { 
                    "range" : { 
                        "date" : { "gte" : "2011-01-01"} 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Now you execute the search against `filtered_people` instead of the underlying `people` index:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/filtered_people/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "term": {
                  "weight": 70
               }
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Which will return just the doc you are interested in:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "people",
            "_type": "ata",
            "_id": "AUudZPUfCSiheYJkTW-h",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Jules",
               "weight": 70,
               "date": "2010-01-01"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about filtered aliases. Thanks Zach!

Comment: Np, happy to help :)  Filtered aliases end up being super useful for hiding boilerplate logic from your application.  They don't carry a performance cost either, so go wild :)